# Android: External SD Card storage size

Tags: android, sd-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Active SGH-I537. I let it format my 64 GB SDHC card. It used exFAT format. I then transfered my MP3 collection to it, which is about 34 GB. When I finished, I noticed that I had only 15.4 GB left, so it used up 47 GB! If I check the folders' properties it only displays 7 GB. It doesn't add up.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvJHd.png)

[image: Properties]

I am guessing the size allocation might be set to big. Can I format it with a different size allocation on my Windows 7 PC and have it still be compatible with my android phone and regain some more space?